# Replacing the ellipsis with three dots

Tags: excerpt

I'm having an issue with the ellipsis generated by `the_excerpt()`. I'm using a custom font which doesn't have the ellipsis character, therefore I just have a random character instead of the usual `...`

I'm looking for a way to totally disable the three dots from turning into an ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm not 100% sure I understood your question correctly but give this a try if you want to replace that excerpt [...] with anything you want. You can use this hook to manipulate that. Where "More" is after the &nbsp you can use what ever you'd like or even use CSS to change it's styles. Paste this in your functions.php and edit it to fit your needs.

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' <a class="excerpt-dot" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' . __('>&nbsp;More', 'your-text-domain') . '</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```